# Add a column value depending on a date range (if-else)

Tags: python, pandas, date, dataframe

I have a date column in my dataframe and want to add a column called location. The value of location in each row should depend on which date range it falls under.

For example, the date 13th November falls between 12th November and 16th November & therefore the location should be Seattle. The date 17th November falls between 17th November and 18th November and must be New York.

Below is an example of the data frame I want to achieve

```
Dates     | Location (column I want to add)
.............................................
11/12/2017| Seattle
11/13/2017| Seattle
11/14/2017| Seattle
11/15/2017| Seattle
11/16/2017| Seattle
11/17/2017| New York
11/18/2017| New York
11/19/2017| London
11/20/2017| London
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create dictionary of locations with start and end dates first, then loop by dict and set values by [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and [`between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html):

```
d = {'Seattle':['2017-11-12','2017-11-16'],
     'New York':['2017-11-17','2017-11-18'],
     'London':['2017-11-19','2017-11-20']}

df['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Dates'], format='%m/%d/%Y')

for k, (s,e) in d.items():
    df.loc[df['Dates'].between(s,e), 'Loc'] = k

print (df)
       Dates  Location       Loc
0 2017-11-12   Seattle   Seattle
1 2017-11-13   Seattle   Seattle
2 2017-11-14   Seattle   Seattle
3 2017-11-15   Seattle   Seattle
4 2017-11-16   Seattle   Seattle
5 2017-11-17  New York  New York
6 2017-11-18  New York  New York
7 2017-11-19    London    London
8 2017-11-20    London    London
```

EDIT:

```
d = {'Seattle':[('2017-11-12','2017-11-13'), ('2017-11-15','2017-11-16')],
     'New York':[('2017-11-17','2017-11-18')],
     'London':[('2017-11-19','2017-11-20'), ('2017-11-14','2017-11-14')]}

df['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Dates'], format='%m/%d/%Y')

for k, v in d.items():
    for s, e in v:
        df.loc[df['Dates'].between(s,e), 'Loc'] = k

print (df)
       Dates  Location       Loc
0 2017-11-12   Seattle   Seattle
1 2017-11-13   Seattle   Seattle
2 2017-11-14   Seattle    London
3 2017-11-15   Seattle   Seattle
4 2017-11-16   Seattle   Seattle
5 2017-11-17  New York  New York
6 2017-11-18  New York  New York
7 2017-11-19    London    London
8 2017-11-20    London    London
```

Comment: Hi Jezrael, thank you for your response. Currently, it seems like each location can only have one date range. What if we had multiple date ranges for each location?

Comment: @zosh - added another structure - dictionary with list and tuples, here is possible define multiple ranges per one location.

Comment: let me know if I can buy you a starbucks coffee at a store

Comment: @zosh - Thank you :) But I dont driink coffee :)